# Regex to extract function-name, & it's parameters

Tags: c#, regex

I am building an application where the user can specify an expression for some fields. The expression shall contain functions too. I need to evaluate these expressions and display final value in report.

I had an expression to extract function-name & it's paramters. Previously, the function parameters were decimal values. But now, the parameters can also be expression.

For ex,

```
Round( 1  * (1+  1 /100) % (2 -1), 0)

Function-name : Round
Parameter1    : 1  * (1+  1 /100) % (2 -1)
Parameter2    : 0
```

Previous Regex:

```
string pattern2 = @"([a-zA-Z]{1,})[[:blank:]]{0,}\(([^\(\)]{0,})\)";
```

This regex does not help me anymore to find expression-parameters.

Can someone help me with the right regex to extract function-name & parameters? I am implement all or most of the functions supported by Math class.
The program is built in c#

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Expressions with functions are not a regular language, so you can't assume to be able to parse them with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

```
 "^\s*(\w+)\s*\((.*)\)"
```

group(1) is function name

split group(2) with `","` you get para list.

**updated**

since I don't have Windows system (.Net either), I test it with python. nested function is not a problem. if we add "^\s*" at the beginning of the expression:

```
import re

s="Round(floor(1300 + 0.234 - 1.765), 1)"
m=re.match("^\s*(\w+)\s*\((.*)\)",s)
m.group(1)
Output: 'Round'

m.group(2)
Output: 'floor(1300 + 0.234 - 1.765), 1'
you can split if you like:
m.group(2).split(',')[0]
Out: 'floor(1300 + 0.234 - 1.765)'

m.group(2).split(',')[1]                                                                                                        
Out: ' 1'
```

well, if your function nesting is like `f(a(b,c(x,y)),foo, m(j,k(n,o(i,u))) )`, my code won't work.

Comment: This won’t work. Consider `Round(1) + Round(2)` as an example.

Comment: well, i thought it would be only one function per line, as example shows.

Comment: Expression can have nested functions too. For ex Round(floor(1300 + 0.234 - 1.765), 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a parser, instead of using regular expressions.
The [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) library is (in my opinion) extremely easy to use, and in the examples there's something very similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the post [Regex for matching Functions and Capturing their Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906514/regex-for-matching-functions-and-capturing-their-arguments), you can extract your function using Kent regex and use this code to extract parameters form the last group :

```
string extractArgsRegex = @"(?:[^,()]+((?:\((?>[^()]+|\((?<open>)|\)(?<-open>))*\)))*)+";
var ArgsList = Regex.Matches(m.Groups[m.Groups.Count - 1].Value, extractArgsRegex);
```